# Bash script to create a new txt file with unique random title and new texts

Tags: linux, bash, shell, automation, scripting

I'm working on a Bash script that should create a text file with a unique title and each of the new text files should have new text in the body. 
I tried with the following example.

```
#!/bin/bash
count=10;
for i in `seq -w 1 $count`
do
# (it also should write text into each of the new text files)
touch "IN-USS-NABT-A-TATNov"-$i.txt 
done
```

The above example creates a 1-10 number of files but I am looking for something that should create a random dynamic title in the file with new text on it every time it creates.

Thanks in advance for the help. Greatly appreciated.

Comment: Do you have an example of what you want to write to the file?

Comment: `echo $RANDOM > $RANDOM.txt` ?

Comment: Hi Kamil, This is what I want. Now I want to make date random, that should genearate new date for each file. The date text located at Ln 5 Col 30 -36 on the text body, also Alphanumeric identifier located at Ln 5 Col 38, only one word should be dynamic, starts from 0-9-A-Z (one word ) . #!/bin/bash
count=10;
for i in `seq -w 1 $count`
do
echo "101 021001033 11001100119110806009094101SAVETAILUK             SSS MNSOMEIN TAT               
8220                XX3               UK123456789 IATINBINTDD  HAHUKD1911081701042000010000421
" > IN-UKXNS-NCHCT-S-IAT-TO-RTNnov$RANDOM.txt
done

Answer (score 0):

```
#!/bin/bash

count=10;

# To set a variable to the output of a command, you can use $(command).
for i in $(seq -w 1 $count)
do 
    touch "IN-USS-NABT-A-TATNov"-$i.txt
    # ">" is used to redirect output to a file.
    echo $i > "IN-USS-NABT-A-TATNov"-$i.txt
done
```

Answer (score 0):

You can change the program as it follows:

```
#!/bin/bash

# Generate an aplhanumeric String with variable length
randomString=$( dd if=/dev/urandom bs=15 count=1 | tr -dc 'a-zA-Z0-9' );
fileName="IN-USS-NABT-A-TATNov"-$randomString.txt    

# Check that the generated string does not conflict with other files
until [ -z `ls | grep "$fileName"` ]; do
    randomString=$( dd if=/dev/urandom bs=15 count=1 | tr -dc 'a-zA-Z0-9' );
    fileName="IN-USS-NABT-A-TATNov"-$randomString.txt   
done

# Once you have an unique file name create the file and fill it
echo "$randomString" > $fileName;
```

If you want to fill the file with random symbols too you can do:

```
fileContent=`echo $randomString | base64`;
echo $fileContent > $fileName;
```

I hope this helps you.

Answer (score 0):

Alternative to solution of Ethan:

```
#!/bin/bash

# semicolon removed
count=10

# numerical version of 'for'
for (( i = 1; i <= count; i++ ))
do
    # here we use printf to get a number with at least 2 digits
    printf -v num %02d $i

    # touch is not needed, because the following line
    # will create and update timestamps too

    # create and touch file. Text is an UUID.
    uuidgen > "IN-USS-NABT-A-TATNov-$num.txt"
done
```

Comment: Hi Wiimm, Thank you for your answer. I made following one.This is what I want. Now I want to work in the body text to make date random, that should genearate new date for each file. The date text located at Ln 5 Col 30 -36 on the text body, also Alphanumeric identifier located at Ln 5 Col 38, only one word should be dynamic, starts from 0-9-A-Z (one word ) . #!/bin/bash count=10; for i in seq -w 1 $count do echo "101 021001033 11001100119110806009094101SAVETAILUK SSS MNSOMEIN TAT 8220 XX3 UK123456789 IATINBINTDD HAHUKD1911081701042000010000421 " > IN-UKXNS-NCHCT-S-IAT-TO-RTNnov$RANDOM.txt done